# Incremental variable definition

Tags: arrays, variables, checkbox, autoit

I want to automatically define incrementing variable names.

So instead of this:

```
$Var1 = 'This is variable one :P'
$Var2 = 'This is variable two :P'
```

I'd like this (pseudo code):

```
For $i = 1 to UBound($People)-1     
    **$var[$i]** = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox($var[$i], 24, $y, 200, 17) 
    $y = $y + 25 
Next
```

Does anyone know how?

The code should make as many checkboxes as defined in an array and every checkbox should have its own variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `Assign()`:

```
For $i = 1 To 5
    Assign('var' & $i, $i);
Next
```

Then you can access these variables with:

```
MsgBox(4096, "My dynamic variables", $var1)
MsgBox(4096, "My dynamic variables", $var3)
MsgBox(4096, "My dynamic variables", $var5)
```

Obviously, `var2` and `var3` can be used too. What you should have done was storing those values in an array.

Comment: @DemonWareXT "_You're looking for the `Assign` function!_" Wasn't that to be avoided ("_so instead of this_")?

Answer (score -1):

> so instead of this:
>
> ```
> $Var1 = 'This is variable one :P'
> $Var2 = 'This is variable two :P'
> ```
>
> I'd like this (pseudo code):
>
> ```
> For $i = 1 to UBound($People)-1   
>     **$var[$i]** = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox($var[$i], 24, $y, 200, 17) 
>     $y = $y + 25 
> Next
> ```
>
> Does anyone know how this could be done?

As per [Documentation - Intro - Arrays](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_variables.htm):

> An Array is a variable containing a series of data elements. Each element in this variable can be accessed by an index number which relates to the position of the element within the Array - in AutoIt the first element of an Array is always element [0]. Arrays elements are stored in a defined order and can be sorted.

Dynamic checkbox creation example, assigning multiple [checkbox-control](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlCreateCheckbox.htm) identifiers to a single array (untested, no error-checking):

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

Global Const $g_iBoxStartX = 25
Global Const $g_iBoxStartY = 25
Global Const $g_iBoxWidth  = 100
Global Const $g_iBoxHeight = 15
Global Const $g_iBoxSpace  = 0
Global Const $g_iBoxAmount = Random(2, 20, 1)
Global Const $g_iBoxTextEx = $g_iBoxAmount -1
Global Const $g_sBoxTextEx = 'Your text here.'

Global Const $g_iWindDelay = 50
Global Const $g_iWinWidth  = $g_iBoxWidth * 2
Global Const $g_iWinHeight = ($g_iBoxStartY * 2) + ($g_iBoxHeight * $g_iBoxAmount) + ($g_iBoxSpace * $g_iBoxAmount)
Global Const $g_sWinTitle  = 'Example'

Global       $g_hGUI
Global       $g_aID

Main()

Func Main()

    $g_hGUI = GUICreate($g_sWinTitle, $g_iWinWidth, $g_iWinHeight)
    $g_aID  = GUICtrlCreateCheckboxMulti($g_iBoxStartX, $g_iBoxStartY, $g_iBoxWidth, $g_iBoxHeight, $g_iBoxSpace, $g_iBoxAmount)

    GUICtrlSetData($g_aID[$g_iBoxTextEx], $g_sBoxTextEx)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $g_hGUI)

    While Not (GUIGetMsg() = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE)

        Sleep($g_iWindDelay)

    WEnd

    Exit
EndFunc

Func GUICtrlCreateCheckboxMulti(Const $iStartX, Const $iStartY, Const $iWidth, Const $iHeight, Const $iSpace, Const $iAmount, Const $sTextTpl = 'Checkbox #%s')
    Local $iYPosCur = 0
    Local $sTextCur = ''
    Local $aID[$iAmount]

    For $i1 = 0 To $iAmount -1

        $iYPosCur = $iStartY + ($iHeight * $i1) + ($iSpace * $i1)
        $sTextCur = StringFormat($sTextTpl, $i1 +1)
        $aID[$i1] = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox($sTextCur, $iStartX, $iYPosCur, $iWidth, $iHeight)

    Next

    Return $aID
EndFunc
```

- `GUICtrlCreateCheckboxMulti()` demonstrates

  - array declaration (`$aID[$iAmount]`)
  - assignment of array elements in a [`For...To...Step...Next`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/For.htm) -loop (`$aID[$i1] = ...`).
- `Main()` demonstrates selection of an individual element (changing its text using [`GUICtrlSetData()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetData.htm)).
- Adjust constants as required (`$g_iBoxAmount` etc.).