# Using variables in setting variables

Tags: autoit

I want to enumerate a variable as so:

```
$x = 0
Do
  $x+=1
  $Day$x = True
Until $x = 7
```

The above returns a syntax error on `$Day$x` (because it's only supposed to see one variable in the command). So basically, I want `$Day1 = True`, `$Day2 = True`, so on and so forth. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Normal shell way to do this would be `${Day$x}`, but I have no idea if that works with autoit

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44510404/4157124).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of arrays.

```
#include <Array.au3> ; for debugging

Global $Day[7]
$x = 0
Do
    $Day[$x] = True
    $x+=1
Until $x = 7

_ArrayDisplay($Day) ; For debugging
```

You can actually do what you originally described with $Day1, $Day2, $Day3 but it would be a **very bad** programming practice and I personally strongly discourage it. That being said, it is possible with the Assign function. You'd be using it for totally the wrong reason. But for completeness, here's how:

```
$x = 0
Do
    Assign("Day" & $x, True)
    $x+=1
Until $x = 7

MsgBox(0, "", $Day2)
```