# How can I clean up this code to be shorter?

Tags: autoit

I'm using AutoIt:

```
$1 = GetItemBySlot(1, 1) 
$2 = GetItemBySlot(1, 2) 
$3 = GetItemBySlot(1, 3) 
$4 = GetItemBySlot(1, 4)  
$5 = GetItemBySlot(1, 5)
```

The code repeats for 40 lines. How can I shorten it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten this by using [Assign()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Assign.htm) and 
[Eval()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Eval.htm).

```
For $i = 1 To 5
    Assign($i, GetItemBySlot(1, $i))
Next
```

That would be 3 lines instead of *n* lines. During runtime this will be expanded to:

```
Assign(1, GetItemBySlot(1, 1))
Assign(2, GetItemBySlot(1, 2))
Assign(3, GetItemBySlot(1, 3))
Assign(4, GetItemBySlot(1, 4))
Assign(5, GetItemBySlot(1, 5))
```

To get the data of those variables you need to use the `Eval` function. So

```
For $i = 1 To 5
    Eval($i)
Next
```

returns the value of `GetItemBySlot(1, $i)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For $i = 1 To 40

   $aItemsBySlot[$i] = GetItemBySlot(1, $i)

Next
```

As per [Documentation - Intro - Arrays](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_variables.htm):

> An Array is a variable containing a series of data elements. Each element in this variable can be accessed by an index number which relates to the position of the element within the Array - in AutoIt the first element of an Array is always element [0]. Arrays elements are stored in a defined order and can be sorted.

Example in `GetItemBySlotMulti()` (untestes, no error-checking):

```
Global $aItems

; Assign:
$aItems = GetItemBySlotMulti(1, 40)

; Retrieve single value (output item #1 to console):
ConsoleWrite($aItems[1] & @CRLF)

; Retrieve all values:
For $i = 1 To $aItems[0]

   ConsoleWrite($aItems[$i] & @CRLF)

Next

; Retrieve amount of items:
ConsoleWrite($aItems[0] & @CRLF)

; Re-assign a single value (re-assign item #1):
$aItems[1] = GetItemBySlot(1, 1)

; Function (used to assign example):
Func GetItemBySlotMulti(Const $iSlot, Const $iItems)
   Local $aItemsBySlot[$iItems +1]
         $aItemsBySlot[0] = $iItems

   For $i = 1 To $iItems

      $aItemsBySlot[$i] = GetItemBySlot($iSlot, $i)

   Next

   Return $aItemsBySlot
EndFunc
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482045/autoit-incremental-variable-definition/44510404#44510404).