# How to convert text lines to variables?

Tags: variables, variable-assignment, autoit, bulk

Check out [this list](http://pastebin.com/99jCTFpV). I need each one turned into a variable and set equal to 0. Example:

```
;1-Methyoxy-2-Propanol would be:
$OneMethoxyTwoPropanol = 0

;and 1,2-BUTADIENE would be:
$OneTwoButadiene = 0
```

Assigning them to a variable wouldn't be a problem, but there are 1500 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i had to do this work i'll make it this way :

- I'll change the case of each word :

[Regex to change to sentence case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039226/regex-to-change-to-sentence-case)

- Make a "SearchAndReplace" :

  > 1 -> One
  >
  > 2 -> Two
  >
  > ...
  >
  > {underscore} -> ''
  >
  > {space} -> ''
  >
  > ...
- Then in a soft like SublimeText i'll add a `$` in front of each line and a `= 0` at the end. With the help of the `Ctrl+Shift+L`

Maybe you could use a regex to help you in the "SearchAndReplace" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Local $sFilePath = @DesktopDir & "\test.ini"
Local $aArray = IniReadSection($sFilePath, "Variables")
Local $aVariablesArray[UBound($aArray)][2]

For $i = 1 To $aArray[0][0]
    $aVariablesArray[$i][0] = $aArray[$i][0]
    $aVariablesArray[$i][1] = $aArray[$i][1]
Next

For $i = 1 To UBound($aVariablesArray) -1
    MsgBox(0, "", "Variable: " & $aVariablesArray[$i][0] & @CRLF & "Value: " & $aVariablesArray[$i][1])
Next
```

Your ini file should look like this

```
[Variables]
firstvariable=0
secondvariable=0
etc...=0
```

To create an ini file just open notepad, write down the file and then save it as .ini.

You can use RegEx to rename each file according to your needs.
The array created is a 2d array. It is needed to store the variable's name and value.

Comment: Alternative, but pretty much equivalent, methods would include using maps (a feature of some of the latest beta versions) or a Scripting.Dictionary object, instead of a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Notepad++, so I'm not sure if this would work with any other IDEs/Notepads. I'm going to be using `1-Methoxy-2-Propanol` for my following example.

1. I learned not to start variables with numbers, so I needed to replace them with words. `1-Methoxy-2-Propanol` contains a `1` and a `2`, we need to change these to `One` and `Two`.
   Starting product:

   ```
   1-Methoxy-2-Propanol
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and move to the replace tab. In the "Find what:" box, type `1`. In the "Replace with:" box, type `One`, then press "replace all" (not just "replace"). Do this for numbers zero (0) through nine (9). Now, your product will look like this:

   ```
   One-Methoxy-Two-Propanol
   ```
3. Next we need to get rid of the dashes. In the Replace tab, inside of the "Find what:" box, type `-` and in the "Replace With:" box, backspace completely so there is nothing there, then press "Replace All". Now, your product will look like this:

   ```
   OneMethoxyTwoPropanol
   ```
4. There are other products that include comas and parenthesis, so simply find and replace these like above.
5. We need to add `$` to the beginning of each word. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> again and go to the Replace tab. In the "Find what:" box, type `^` which symbolizes the start of a new line. In the "Replace with:" box, type `$` and press "Replace All". This will make your product look like:

   ```
   $OneMethoxyTwoPropanol
   ```
6. We need to set all of these variables zero! Go back to the replace tab. In the "Find what:" box type `\r`. In the "Replace with:" box, type `= 0`. Note the space before the equal sign. Press "Replace All". Your product will look like this:

   ```
   $OneMethoxyTwoPropanol = 0
   ```

Your file should have started like this:

```
1-Methoxy-2-Propanol
1,2-BUTADIENE
2-Diethyl aminoethanol
2-ETHYL HEXANOL
2-ETHYL HEXYL ACRYLATE
2-Ethyl hexyl lights
2-Ethyl phenol
2-Ethylsuccionitrile
2-Methyl piperidine
2-Methyl-2-Butene nitrile
2-Methyl-2-Pentenal
2-Methyl-3-Butene nitrile
2-Methylglutaronitrile
2-Pentene nitrile
2,4,7,9-Tetramethyl-5-decyne-4
```

And ended up like this:

```
$OneMethoxyTwoPropanol = 0
$OneTwoBUTADIENE = 0
$TwoDiethylaminoethanol = 0
$TwoETHYLHEXANOL = 0
$TwoETHYLHEXYLACRYLATE = 0
$TwoEthylhexyllights = 0
$TwoEthylphenol = 0
$TwoEthylsuccionitrile = 0
$TwoMethylpiperidine = 0
$TwoMethylTwoButenenitrile = 0
$TwoMethylTwoPentenal = 0
$TwoMethylThreeButenenitrile = 0
$TwoMethylglutaronitrile = 0
$TwoPentenenitrile = 0
$TwoFourSevenNineTetramethylFivedecyneFour = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

stringreplace and assign will do the job. If the amount of number to word replacements becomes too large you may consider storing those rather than nesting replace functions.

```
$sStr = "1-Methyoxy-2-Propanol" & @LF & "1,2-BUTADIENE"

$sStr = stringreplace(stringreplace(stringreplace(stringreplace($sStr , "," , "-") , "1-" , "One") , "2-" , "Two") , "-" , "")

$aStr = stringsplit($sStr , @LF , 2)

    For $i = 0 to ubound($aStr) - 1
        Assign($aStr[$i] , 0)
    Next

msgbox(0, '' , Eval("OneMethyoxyTwoPropanol") & @LF & Eval("OneTwoBUTADIENE"))
```

Answer (score -1):

> I simply need to turn them into a variable and set them equal to 0.

As per [Documentation - Intro - Arrays](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_variables.htm):

> An Array is a variable containing a series of data elements. Each element in this variable can be accessed by an index number which relates to the position of the element within the Array - in AutoIt the first element of an Array is always element [0]. Arrays elements are stored in a defined order and can be sorted.

Removes lines containing list names (`; List I` etc.) and empty (or less than three character-) lines (as per `$g_sRegexFilter`). Stores remaining lines to 2D array-elements. Example:

```
#include <StringConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global Enum  $ITEM_NAME, _
             $ITEM_VALUE

Global Const $g_sFilePath    = 'C:\list.txt'
Global Const $g_sFileNewline = @CRLF
Global Const $g_sRegexFilter = '(?m)^(.{0,2}\v)|(;.*\v)$'
Global Const $g_sItemHeader  = 'name|value'

Global       $g_sFileText    = ''
Global       $g_aFileItems

$g_sFileText  = _TextFromFile($g_sFilePath)
$g_sFileText  = StringRegExpReplace($g_sFileText, $g_sRegexFilter, '')
$g_aFileItems = StringSplit($g_sFileText, $g_sFileNewline, $STR_ENTIRESPLIT + $STR_NOCOUNT)
_ArrayColInsert($g_aFileItems, $ITEM_VALUE)

For $i1 = 0 To UBound($g_aFileItems) - 1
    $g_aFileItems[$i1][$ITEM_VALUE] = 0
Next

_ArrayDisplay($g_aFileItems, '$g_aFileItems', '', 0, Default, $g_sItemHeader)

Func _TextFromFile(Const $sFile)
    Local       $hFile = FileOpen($sFile, $FO_READ + $FO_UTF8_NOBOM)
    Local Const $sData = FileRead($hFile)

    FileClose($hFile)
    Return $sData
EndFunc
```

Returns:

```
1-Methoxy-2-Propanol      | 0
1,2-BUTADIENE             | 0
2-Diethyl aminoethanol    | 0
2-ETHYL HEXANOL           | 0
2-ETHYL HEXYL ACRYLATE    | 0
2-Ethyl hexyl lights      | 0
2-Ethyl phenol            | 0
2-Ethylsuccionitrile      | 0
2-Methyl piperidine       | 0
2-Methyl-2-Butene nitrile | 0
2-Methyl-2-Pentenal       | 0
2-Methyl-3-Butene nitrile | 0
2-Methylglutaronitrile    | 0
...
```

As:

```
$g_aFileItems[ x ][$ITEM_NAME]
$g_aFileItems[ x ][$ITEM_VALUE]
```

Add additional columns using [`_ArrayColInsert()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayColInsert.htm).

> ... as there are 1500 of them.

Consider using [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44659073/4157124). [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26442290/4157124).